# Magento 1.5.0.1 admin: Unable to add custom url rewrite in mutistore installation

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, custom-url

In order to fix some 404s as reported by Webmaster tools, I need to add some custom URL rewrites (URL redirects) on a per-store basis to my multi-store Magento installation, but I am unable to do that: as soon as I select the "Custom" URL rewrite type from the top selector, a custom URL Rewrite edit form appears, but there are no stores selectable in "Store" dropdown list, and - since Store is a required field, Magento admin doesn't let me save the redirect.

Can anyone spread some light on this? My Magento version is 1.5.0.1, but if this is a bug, as I suspect, it might be present in other (even more recent) versions as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug indeed. To fix this, apply the following patch or simply replace line 120 of your app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Edit/Form.php with these lines.

I would suggest you don't modify the "core" file directly, but create the same folder structure in app/code/local instead, copy the core file there and edit it. Files with the same path in "local" have higher priority and will be loaded instead of those in "core" by Magento, they are also more easy to spot and eventually remove, restoring default Magento functionality, if needed in future.

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Edit/Form.php => app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Urlrewrite/Edit/Form.php

119a120,130

> ```
> 120:     } else {
> 121:        foreach ($stores as $i => $store) {
> 122:            if (isset($store['value']) && $store['value']) {
> 123:                $found = false;
> 124:                foreach ($store['value'] as $_k => $_v) {
> 125:                    if (isset($_v['value']) && $_v['value']) {
> 126:                        array_push( $entityStores, $_v['value'] );
> 127:                    }
> 128:                }
> 129:            }
> 130:        }
> ```